# Search dynamoDB using more than one attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, alexa-skills-kit

I've created a skill with the help of a few people on this site.

I have a database and what I want to do is ask Alexa to recall data from my database. I.e. by asking for films from a certain date

The issue im having at the moment is I have defined my partition key and it works correctly for one of my items in my table and will read the message for that specific key, but anything else i search it gives me the same response as the one item that works. Any ideas on how to overcome this?

Here is how i have defined my table:

```js
let handleCinemaIntent = (context, callback) => {    
  let params = {
    TableName: "cinema",
    Key: {
        date: "2018-01-04",
    }
  };
```

Just as a side note, I will have the same date repeating in my partition key and from what I understand, the partition key needs to be unique; so i'd need to overcome this.

Answer (score 2):

You have a few options for structuring your DynamoDB table but I think the most straightforward is the following:

You can set up your table with a partition key of "date" (like you have now), but also with a [sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.CoreComponents.html#HowItWorks.CoreComponents.PrimaryKey) which would be the film name, or some other identifier. This way, you can have all films for a particular date under one partition key and query them using a [Query](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html) operation (as opposed to the GetItem that you've been using). You won't be able to modify the existing table to add a sort key though, so you will have to delete the existing table and recreate it with the different schema.

Since there is generally a rather limited number of films for each day, this partition scheme should work really well, assuming you always just query by day. Where this breaks down is if you need to search by just film name (ie. "give me the dates when this film will run"). If you need the latter, then you could create a GSI where the primary key is the film name, and the range key is the date.

However, you should pause a moment and consider whether DynamoDB is the right database for your needs. I say this because Dynamo is really good at access patterns where you know exactly what you are searching for and you need to be able to scale horizontally. Whereas your use case is more of a fuzzy search.

As an alternative to Dynamo you might consider setting up an ElasticSearch cluster and throwing your film data in it. Then you can very trivially run queries like "what films will run on this day", or "what days will this film run", or "what films will run this week", or "what action movies are coming this spring", "what animation films are playing today", "what movies are playing near me"

Comment: Thanks for your reply, do you have a link to how i can set up an elastic search cluster? As i intend to use this similar model for more fuzzy searches not to do with movies

Comment: Just make sure you read in on setting up an ElasticSearch cluster, this is NOT a trivial thing to do. Also the hosted one that AWS provides is generally considered to be the worst EC cluster on the planet, so if you want easy and have some money go with the Elastic Cloud offering from the AWS marketplace.

Comment: @zuba - here's a link to get you started with a simple ElasticSearch cluster on AWS. SDM is right that ElasticSearch is not as _seemingly_ simple as DynamoDB but it is not that difficult either (and DynamoDB is no piece of cake either, though ti looks easy at first glance)

Comment: @zuba, also here is a link to the official ElasticSearch client for NodeJS: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-js

Comment: @Mike-Dinescu thanks you guys, i'll go over it today. Before i do so, could you kindly help set my parameters for my skill to work with the dynamo db table (as i'd rather have something that works in place)

Comment: @zuba ehat parameters are you looking for? As I mentioned in the answer you could recreate the table to have a partition key of "date" and a sort key of "filmname", both string. Then you update your function to retrieve the data using these keys.

Comment: @MikeDinescu Could you help me with updating my function to work with the sort key aswell?

Comment: Have you reconfigured your table?

Comment: @MikeDinescu yes ive reconfigured my table to have a sort key, i have also linked it to my lambda function, ive tried a few different things but cant seem to get it to work correctly

Comment: @zuba if you had recreated the table with a string partition key named "date" and a string range key named "filmname" then the code that I had in the other example should have worked just fine. please ask another question with details. Please include the table schema, the code you tried and the error message you are getting.

Comment: @mikedinescu im getting the same issue i originally had where it would only recall the message from the defined parameter

Comment: @SDM hi sorry to bother you again, wanted to ask if elastic search can be used on alexa? Because for my use case i need voice integration to request the data im looking for

Comment: Yes, Alexa skills can use elasticSearch